Is the question about abuser treatment broad anymore?
The question

How likely abusers with low motivation to change actually be aware of the hurt they made after having legal issue?

has now been edited to

Why is the effectiveness of treatments for abusers and offenders low?

Is the new one broad anymore?

I think the question has improved a lot and I've voted to re-open. As this vote is a mod vote, it overrides the normal voting procedure of the community. As a result, the post has been re-opened immediately. Since I was the one to close it, I felt it was justified to go for a mod vote, mainly because there are not many users around that [have the necessary privilege to] actively participate in the reviewing process.
